# Need help getting results to a specific tab

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Hello I am trying to get the below code to print the results of this query to a different tab in the excel document, so I can have a button on the summary page and results exported to a specific tab. Everything works fine on the import to the tab with the macro on it but doesnt want to print to a separate sheet. Any help would be great!

```
    Cells.Select
Range("A3").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A3").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1" & Now, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(""website""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=15, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   " & _
    " #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Issue Type"", type text}, {""Custom field (Epic Name)"", type text}, {""Summary"", type text}, {""Assignee"", type text}, {""Reporter"", type text}, {""Status"", type text}, {""Resolution"", type text}, {""Created"", type datetime}, {" & _
    """Updated"", type datetime}, {""Due Date"", type datetime}, {""Component/s"", type text}, {""Component/s_1"", type text}, {""Component/s_2"", type text}, {""Custom field (Status Update)"", type text}, {""Custom field (Epic Link)"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Visible = False

While ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
Wend
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to print the results to Sheet2, you could try changing this:

```
, Destination:=Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
```

to this:

```
, Destination:=Sheet2.Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
```

Comment: I tried that and I got an error stating the worksheet data for the table needs to be on the same sheet as the table

Comment: It sounds like it can't be done.  Maybe you will have to add some code to copy the data to a new sheet.

Comment: Thanks guys! Based on this I just activated the sheet at the start of the macro that I wanted it to go to and that works